# PHP: Можно ли с помощью классов (интерфейсов или трейтов) сильно сократить код, который повторяется, но всегда чуть другой

Tags: php, функции, классы, интерфейс, рефакторинг

Есть парсер, который скачивает с сайта множество архивов, затем, каждый обрабатывает и данные из него кладет в таблицу. Таблицы не связаны между собой, у каждого архива могут быть свои проблемы с данными, например, у одного нужно перевести из одной кодировки, у другого - из другой. Для какой-то таблицы нужно по ходу обработки добавить в таблицу какую-то отметку, в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия в заархивированной бд информации. Одним словом, приходится делать длинную вереницу функций, который очень похожи, но немного отличаются. Выглядит это так:

1. Парсер архивов.
2. function 1 (для закидывания в таблицу первого архива).
3. function 2 (для закидывания в таблицу второго)

и тд. много функций

Код, к сожалению не могу привести... Если можно с помощью объектно-ориентированного программирования как-то отрефакторить это, то хотел спросить знающих, как. Мне бы только понимать принцип, так как тогда буду знать что искать... С объектно-ориентированным программированием знаком очень слабо...

Comment: без конкретики в коде мало что вам можно посоветовать для рефакторинга. советы будут весьма общими и маловероятно что вы поймете как их применить на практике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и нужно.
Вот ознакомьтесь с данными статьями, [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/336788/) как раз описывается ваша проблема в пункте:
***Уберите дублирующий код***

И можно почитать еще [тут](https://github.com/peter-gribanov/clean-code-php#%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5)